# I could not push an new data into array when use upsert

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I could not push an new_data into array when use upsert

How could I use upsert to insert/update one document  ?

`history` is an array.

By the way, the gem `mongo`'s data' seems much much less popular than `Python` or `Javascript`.

Is gem `mongo` has less functions than other languages and has more bugs ?

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)

```
[64] pry(#<Scoot>)> @db.data_collection.find({_id: data[:_id]}).update_one(
[64] pry(#<Scoot>)*   {data: data,
[64] pry(#<Scoot>)*     from: from_city,
[64] pry(#<Scoot>)*   },
[64] pry(#<Scoot>)*   {:$push => { "history" => new_data }},
[64] pry(#<Scoot>)*   :upsert => true,
[64] pry(#<Scoot>)*   :safe => true
[64] pry(#<Scoot>)* )
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
```

> Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$push' in '$push' is not valid for storage. (52)

```
@db.data_collection.find({_id: data[:_id]}).update_one(
  {data: data,
    from: from_city,
    :$push => { "history" => new_data },
    },
  :upsert => true,
  :safe => true
)
```

## UPDATE GEM MONGO 2.0.4

```
collection.find({_id: data[:_id]}).update_one(
  {
    "$set" => {
      "city" => from_city
    },
    "$push": => { "history" => new_data }
  },
  :upsert => true
)
```

### ERROR

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting end-of-input
[105] pry(#<Scoot>)> :upsert => true
SyntaxError: unexpected =>, expecting end-of-input
:upsert => true
          ^
[105] pry(#<Scoot>)> )
SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are using the 2.X driver series here. Mostly the problem is that the `:$push` syntax is not supported, so you write it differently. Also, `:safe` is long deprecated wherever you read that from. Plus you use `"$set` when you want to set specific fields of an Object:

```
@db.data_collection.find({ _id: data[:_id]}).update_one({
      "$set" => { 
          "data" => data,
          "city" => from_city
      },
      "$push" => { "history" => new_data }
  },
  :upsert => true
)
```

See the documentation for [`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection/View/Writable.html#update_one-instance_method)

Comment: your solution still not works. pls see my update thanks,

Comment: @user3675188 It's a typo. Remove the `:` after $push

Comment: THanks so much, your explination is much helpful than poor formal documentation.

Comment: @user3675188 I'll admit that the ruby documentation is one of the worst. The core MongoDB documentation has better examples, just be aware of changing the syntax to ruby specs where required. Also note that in the 2.X driver series ( and most other language recent drivers ) the actual options and methods are modelled using the "Bulk API" underneath. So it's those calling methods that are most relevant.